# Next.js unable to find font file

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use next.js localFont, like so:

```
const Eina = localFont({
  src: "../public/fonts/eina01.ttf",
});
```

However, no matter where i place the eina file/whatever file path I try, it always gives me:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@next/font/local/target.css?{"path":"pages/_app.js","import":"","arguments":[{"src":"../public/fonts/eina01.ttf"}],"variableName":"Eina"}'
```

its currently placed in public/fonts, but I tried to place it in the pages like said in the docs, with no luck either. How am i meant to import the font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to import the fontfile in a CSS-file like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Cutiful";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("./cutiful.otf");
}
```

In this example the fontfile is located in the same directory as the CSS-file.
Make sure to import the CSS-file in your RootLayout with `import "./globals.css"` or whatever the name of your CSS-file is. In your JSX you can then add classNames to tags like this:

```
<div className="myClass">some text in a div-tag</div>
```

and the styling is done in the CSS-file again, for example:

```
.myClass {
    font-family: "Cutiful", cursive;
    font-size: 3.4rem;
}
```

If you insist on using localFont, look here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/font or here: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/font

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have mentioned the path for font as `public/font`, but you have given the path in src as

```js
src: "../public/fonts/eina01.ttf",
```

I think you just need to change it to

```js
src: "../public/font/eina01.ttf",
```

Or, If it was just a typo in your question, please comment here.

Comment: oh sorry, yeah that was a typo, its actually public/fonts